# Is there a way of running tests within testcafe without it automatically inserting local host infront of the URL

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, iframe, testcafe

So everytime I run a test with testcafe, in the URL I tend to get something like http://10.0.75.1:11111/randomCharacters/ThenActualURLHere

is there a way where it just goes to the actual URL I want it to navigate to without the localhost at the start of the URL?

As I've got an issue, the screen I'm attempting to get to is an iFrame with an angular app within the iFrame, however whenever I navigate to the screen, the iFrame is not loading and I get a js error within the console tab of dev tools stating: "failed to load module script the server responded with a non-javascript mime type of text/html. Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec"

However when I'm manually navigating to the screen (without the localhost in the URL) the iFrame loads fine without any js errors.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to run it by ignoring js errors?  Example, if you are running from command line: testcafe ie tests/sample-fixture.js -e.  https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html

Comment: Yeah, the issue is the js errors actually seem to stop the iFrame actually loading on the screen. So even if I ignore the js errors the iFrame still won't load

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible since TestCafe uses a URL-rewriting proxy which allows it to work without the WebDriver. It looks like you found an error. If you can create an example that can be run locally, please create an issue in the TestCafe repository - https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md.